# Json request works in javascript but not in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm trying to get a JSON object with PHP. When I try it with Jquery it works fine, but when I try the same with PHP, it returns me a timetout message.

Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.post("https://xxxxx/mig_search", {Keywords: 'test'}, function(result){
        var myObj = JSON.parse(result);
        $("body").html(result);
    });
});
```

PHP code:

```
$url = "https://xxxxx/mig_search";

$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'Keywords' => 'teste',
    )
);

$options = array('http' =>
    array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'header' => 'User-Agent: request',
    'content' => $postdata,
));

$ctx = stream_context_create($options);

$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $ctx);
if (!empty($result)) {
    echo $result;
} else {
    echo "Nao funcionou!";
}
die;
```

Comment: You should use Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded in the header

Comment: Why not use curl?

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys. I'm going to try also with curl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below code

```
$postdata = http_build_query(array ('Keywords' => 'teste'));

$options = array (
'http' => array (
    'method' => 'POST',
    'header'=> "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
        . "Content-Length: " . strlen($postdata) . "\r\n",
    'content' => $postdata
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Your code works fine also with PHP when I tried with the JSON from this page https://www.w3schools.com/js/demo_file.php. But when I try with the endpoint that I have on my server made with python, it doesn't work, but it works only with the javascript code. Do you have any idea what it could be?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a Content-Header:

```
'header'=> "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
            . "Content-Length: " . strlen($postdata) . "\r\n",
```